# Are methods that modify reference type parameters bad?

Tags: c#, side-effects

I've seen methods like this:

```
public void Foo(List<string> list)
{
    list.Add("Bar");
}
```

Is this good practice to modify parameters in a method?

Wouldn't this be better?

```
public List<string> Foo(List<string> list)
{
    // Edit
    List<string> newlist = new List<string>(list);
    newlist.Add("Bar");
    return newlist;
}
```

It just feels like the first example has unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the example you've given, the first seems a lot nicer to me than the second. If I saw a method that accepted a list and also returned a list, my first assumption would be that it was returning a new list and not touching the one it was given. The second method, therefore, is the one with unexpected side effects.

As long as your methods are named appropriately there's little danger in modifying the parameter. Consider this:

```
public void Fill<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    // add a bunch of items to list
}
```

With a name like "Fill" you can be pretty certain that the method will modify the list.

Comment: The problem I have is that I've got into the habit of expecting that methods never modify the parameters. Not sure how I got into that habit.

Comment: You should look into F# - sounds like functional programming would be right up your alley.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, in this case, both methods do more or less the same thing. Both will modify the `List` that was passed in.

If the objective is to have lists immutable by such a method, the second example should make a copy of the `List` that was sent in, and then perform the `Add` operation on the new `List` and then return that.

I'm not familiar with C# nor .NET, so my guess would be something along the line of:

```
public List<string> Foo(List<string> list)
{
    List<string> newList = (List<string>)list.Clone();
    newList.Add("Bar");
    return newList;
}
```

This way, the method which calls the `Foo` method will get the newly created `List` returned, and the original `List` that was passed in would not be touched.

This really is up to the "contract" of your specifications or API, so in cases where `List`s can just be modified, I don't see a problem with going with the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the exact same thing in both methods, just one of them is returning the same list.

It really depends on what you're doing, in my opinion.  Just make sure your documentation is clear on what is going on.  Write pre-conditions and post-conditions if you're into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The advent of extension methods has made it a bit easier to deal with methods that introduce side effects.  For example, in your example it becomes much more intuitive to say

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static void AddBar(this List<string> list)
  {
     list.Add("Bar");
  }
}
```

and call it with

```
mylist.AddBar();
```

which makes it clearer that something is happening to the list.

As mentioned in the comments, this is most useful on lists since modifications to a list can tend to be more confusing. On a simple object, I would tend to just to modify the object in place.

Comment: This seems to answer the actual question, i.e. is the first style problematic in that it doesn't make it obvious from a glance that the Foo method changes the parameter passed in.  However, the idea of writing a class, with a method for every value I might want to add/change in a list is crazy.

Comment: I was thinking in terms specifically of lists, as opposed to general access.  I find that my junior developers get thrown with side effects from lists more often than just a normal object.

That being said, there is a line of thought to use read-only properties and set methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not that unexpected that a method that takes a list as parameter modifies the list. If you want a method that only reads from the list, you would use an interface that only allows reading:

```
public int GetLongest(IEnumerable<string> list) {
    int len = 0;
    foreach (string s in list) {
        len = Math.Max(len, s.Length);
    }
    return len;
}
```

By using an interface like this you don't only prohibit the method from changing the list, it also gets more flexible as it can use any collection that implements the interface, like a string array for example.

Some other languages has a `const` keyword that can be applied to parameters to prohibit a method from changing them. As .NET has interfaces that you can use for this and strings that are immutable, there isn't really a need for `const` parameters.